# Versioneer: Accessing version with python module

Tags: python, git, versioning

I am currently using [Versioneer](https://github.com/warner/python-versioneer) to manage the versioning of a python module.  Consistent with convention, my module is structured as follows:

```
root/
|-- python/
|   |-- mymodule
|       |-- _version.py
|       ...
|-- setup.py
|-- versioneer.py
```

I would like to tag output from the python module with the version of the module which generated it.  What is the recommended manner for extracting the version of the module currently running?  I am looking for the version that would be generated if setup.py were executed which would be inclusive of local changes/commits beyond the last git tag.  There seem to be a few ways in which this could be accomplished, however, I am looking for the most conventional/robust.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing `mymodule.__version__` is the most consistent way to extract this information.  This will be appropriately populated with the version information inclusive of commits ahead of last tag, dirty flag, etc.